# Why are PersistentVolumeClaims treated specially by some OpenShift commands

Tags: openshift

Why does the scope `oc get all` (and `oc delete all --all`) in OpenShift 3.10 not include components of type `PersistentVolumeClaim` as well? A separate `oc get pvc` (and `oc delete pvc --all`) is required.

Is there a particular reason for treating these objects special? (Apparently they are only special in some regards; for instance, application templates can create them quite normally along with other components.)

**Update** Components of type `Secret` are also treated special in a perhaps similar way and for similar reasons. One reason I can think of is that these components typically may have longer lifetimes than applications.

Comment: Having ``all`` map to all component types would be dangerous, so good that it doesn't and it only refers to the few that it does. Also, you should really use ``oc delete all --all`` as too much risk of deleting stuff you didn't mean to. Learn to use labels and then use a selector when deleting things. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/working-with-resource-objects/how-do-i-delete-all-resource-objects-for-an-application.html

Comment: Whoops, that should have been "you should not really use ``oc delete all --all``".

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I am actually using `oc delete all --selector app=<app>` in cases when I want to delete *all*.

Comment: It is not (completely?) OpenShift's fault. This is "inherited" from Kubernetes. There are few discussions, like this one here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/151. I remember having to list explicitly secrets, sa, templates, configmaps...after `all` in `oc get all,...` or `oc delete all,... --selector=<...> -n <project>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have by now concluded (also from the comments received) that is behavior is intended by design to guard against accidental deletions of dear persistent storage whose lifetime may substantially exceed single (versions of) applications.

As a consequence, I have now refactored the application template a bit. So far, a single template (YAML file) was in charge of creating all components (except secrets). This led to an "unbalanced" situation which required one `oc new-app --template=app` to create the app, but two `oc delete`s (`oc delete all --selector app=...` and `oc delete pvc --selector app=..`) to delete entirely. After splitting up the template into `app.yaml` and `yaml.yaml` the new, "balanced" arrangement is like this:

```
# create app (including its persistent storage)
oc new-app --template=app
oc new-app --template=pvc

# delete app (including its persistent storage)
oc delete all --selector app=...
oc delete pvc --selector app=...
```

I still leave secrets out of this scope and create them with `oc create secret` once up front.